# Torah Temimah - Edition

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

Can someone recommend an edition of Torah Temimah?

I am looking for an edition that - a) is all-Hebrew b) is accurate c) has nice, clear print.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.sefer.org.il/items/3729214-%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%94-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D

Answer (score 1):

As far as pricing - the cheapest but nice print option is this version [here](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/torah-temimah-with-peirush-full-set/57831) - the text is nice and clear and there is nice delineation between the Chumash text and the accompanying Torah Temimah peirush.

[image]

My personal favourite is the Kesser Melucha edition as shown [here](https://mysefer.com/Chumash-Torah-Temimah---Rabbi-Baruch-HaLevi-Epstein-Chorev-Edition---5-vol.__p-10580.aspx), although it is double the price.

[image]

You can see a sample of the pages [here](https://mysefer.com/showScannedImages.aspx?pfile=10580.jpg).

Comment: The first edition you posted looks excellent. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Feel free to upvote or check as the accepted answer :-)